# CSS issue: overflow-y does not appear inside of the div in the nested div

Tags: html, css

Dealing with a problem, that overflow-y does not appear in inner_messages div, which is located inside of chat_messages div, which is located in chat_big div. I want to create a scroll in the inner_div, and the technique I'm trying to use (that was described [here](http://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/ONoWQd))  does not seem to work...

Is there any proper technique to use in my case?

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#chat_big {
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}

#chat_messages {
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
  height: 550px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 5px solid #01abaa;
}

#inner_messages {
  width: 700px;
  height: 550px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
}

#user_list {
  height: 550px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #01abaa;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 5px solid #fedc3d;
}

#chat_text {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:55px;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat_big">
  <div id="chat_messages">
    <div id="inner_messages">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id = "user_list">
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id = "chat_text" name = "chat_text"></textarea>
    <input type = "button" id = "send_message_button" value = "Send Message"/>
    <input type = "button" id = "user_info_button" value = "Show User Info"/>
    <input type = "button" id = "log_out_button" value = "Log Out"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above css what you have written is correct , scroll will come after `550px` 
add more content inside `inner_messages` div you will get scroll.

If you want see scroll before `550px` decrease the height of `inner_messages` and `chat_messages`